PDF file with blank pages created from ResponseBody
I ran into a problem downloading a PDF file: it is saved with blank pages
My Get request, that returns pdf
@GET("/")
   suspend fun getSomePdf(
      @Query("someQueryParameter") someQueryParameter: String,
   ): ResponseBody

Response:
date: some date
content-type: application/octet-stream
content-length: 101212
...
content-description: File Transfer
content-disposition: attachment; filename="someFileName.pdf"
access-control-allow-origin: https://*.someSite.com
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type
...
%PDF-1.4
...

Creating PDF file:
suspend fun createPdfFromResponseBody(body: ResponseBody, fileName: String): File =
        suspendCoroutine {
            try {
                val pdfDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                val pdfFile = File(pdfDirectory, "someFileName.pdf")

                body.byteStream().use { input ->
                    FileOutputStream(pdfFile).use { output ->
                        input.copyTo(output)
                    }
                    input.close()
                }

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, arrayOf(pdfFile.toString()), arrayOf("application/pdf"), null)
                } else {
                    val mediaScanIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE)
                    mediaScanIntent.data = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile)
                    context.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent)
                }

                it.resume(pdfFile)
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                it.resumeWithException(e)
            }
        }

I've tried everything:

Сhange the Сontent-Type of the response body to application/pdf

val newBody = body.bytes().toResponseBody("application/pdf".toMediaType())


Use okio
And other tips

But all the answers were related to the fact that I need to use responseBody.inputStream(), which did not help me

what do you mean by saving it in binary form?
